# Select only even lines emacs

Tags: multiple-cursors

How can I put a cursor (with `multiple-cursors`) in the beginning of every even line in emacs?
Can I use the regular expression `.*\n.*\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will add a cursor at every even-numbered line. It basically goes to line 2, and starts adding cursors every 2 lines until the end of buffer.

```
(defun mc/mark-even-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    ;; start at line 2
    (forward-line 1)
    (while (progn
             (mc/create-fake-cursor-at-point)
             (eq (forward-line 2) 0))))
  (mc/maybe-multiple-cursors-mode))
```

This is based on the implementation of `mc/toggle-cursor-on-click` from the Multiple Cursors package.